# earliest data and matching field

Tags: sql

i'm stuck on something.  how can i find results for something when the earliest date his to match another field.  say i need to know who bought apples and oranges but bought an apple first.

Cleint 1

```
DATE        Fruit
1st          Orange
2nd          apple
3rd          apple
```

Client 2

```
DATE        Fruit
1st          Apple
2nd          Apple
3rd          Orange
```

Client 3

```
DATE        Fruit
1st          Orange
2nd          Apple 
3rd          Orange
```

I would only want to get the results for client 2.  i've tried variations of Min/Man and concat.  but im not having any luck. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select Client
from t
group by Client
having min(case when Fruit = 'Apple'  then date else null end) 
     < min(case when Fruit = 'Orange' then date else null end)
```

Comment: thanks.  looks like that did the trick!  appreciate the help from everyone on the site.